# mySQL multiple columns in group concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select multiple columns from multiple tables into one single column as a string (since this is part of a larger query)

Basically what I'm trying to do is make sub-groups of an `ID` and a `Name`, The only problem however is that I can't find a way to split these after they already have had a separator assigned to the parent group.

My code:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`mytable1`.`id`, `mytable2`.`name` SEPARATOR  ', ')
FROM `mytable1`
INNER JOIN `mytable2`
    ON `mytable2`.`id` = `mytable1`.`id`
```

What I'm getting:

```
127Name, 153Name, 153Name, etc..
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
127 : Name, 153 : Name, 153 : Name, etc..
```

Is there any way this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat` inside `group_concat`

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`mytable1`.`id`,' : ', `mytable2`.`name`) SEPARATOR  ', ')
```